# i want to change the text in a file, my code is searching the word but not replacing the word

Tags: java

I am trying to replace a string from a js file which have content like this
........ 
minimumSupportedVersion: '1.1.0',
........
now 'm trying to replace the 1.1.0 with 1.1.1. My code is searching the text but not replacing. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
public class replacestring {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    try{
 FileReader fr = new FileReader("G:/backup/default0/default.js");     
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {  
        if(line.contains("1.1.0"))
         {
            System.out.println("searched");
            line.replace("1.1.0","1.1.1");
            System.out.println("String replaced");
         }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are assigning the result of the `replace` to something, otherwise it's lost, remember, `String` is immutable, it can't be changed...

```
line = line.replace("1.1.0","1.1.1");
```

Second, you will need to write the changes back to some file.  I'd recommend that you create a temporary file, to which you can write each `line and when finished, delete the original file and rename the temporary file back into its place

Something like...

```
File original = new File("G:/backup/default0/default.js");
File tmp = new File("G:/backup/default0/tmpdefault.js");
boolean replace = false;
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(original);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tmp);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("1.1.0")) {
            System.out.println("searched");
            line = line.replace("1.1.0", "1.1.1");
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println("String replaced");
        }
    }
    replace = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Doing this here because I want the files to be closed!
if (replace) {
    if (original.delete()) {
        if (tmp.renameTo(original)) {
            System.out.println("File was updated successfully");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Failed to rename " + tmp + " to " + original);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Failed to delete " + original);
    }
}
```

for example.

You may also like to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and make sure you are managing your resources properly

Comment: Ohh yeah, i did miss that. Thanks :) @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Java 7 or above, use the new File I/O API (aka NIO) as

```
// Get the file path
Path jsFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\file.js");

// Read all the contents
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(jsFile);

// Create a buffer
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(
    new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
);

// Search for version code
int pos = buffer.indexOf("1.1.0");
if (pos != -1) {
    // Replace if found
    buffer.replace(pos, pos + 5, "1.1.1");

    // Overwrite with new contents
    Files.write(jsFile,
            buffer.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
}
```

I'm assuming your script file size doesn't cross into MBs; use buffered I/O classes otherwise.